# Language change macro in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice

As the cursor moves in a LibreOffice Writer document, the status below the window shows the language of the characters around the cursor (e.g. *English(USA)*).

Is there a way to run a Macro (named e.g. `LanguageChangeMacro`) when the language name shown in the statusbar changes?

The macro will change the system keyboard layout to simulate a similar functionality of Ms Office Word.